# Getting the Url Image's Resolution in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift

I have a Url image of the server.

Downloading the image cache did not reveal the resolution.

Also, when downloading images synchronously or asynchronously, the resolution of the images was unknown.

How can I get the resolution value of Url Image?

Comment: Define resolution. File Size ? DPI ? Image Dimensions?

Comment: You can’t. You would have to save this info in your server or download it first to check its dimensions. The only thing you can do to avoid downloading all image data is to make a url request for the header and get the expected content size from the response

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Resolved by downloading images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you downloaded the image, you can get the width and height of the image. Use the size property on the UIImage instance. See the documentation below :-

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage

```
let image = UIImage(named:"image.png")
let heightInPoints = image.size.height
let widthInPoints = image.size.width
```

Comment: thank you. I downloaded the image url and found the resolution value safely.